# Strpos from variable

Tags: php, arrays, strpos

The following code prints an array of values where whatever is written in MySearchField is found in the values of $FullLinks:

```
<?
function myFilter($string) {
return strpos($string,'MySearchField') !== false;
}

$newArray = array_filter($FullLinks, 'myFilter');
?>

<pre> <? print_r($newArray); ?> </pre>
```

However, if I use a variable instead then it won't show any values. For example:

```
return strpos($string,$MySearchField) !== false;
```

Can anyone tell me how I can get the search word from a variable instead?

Any actual answers would be really appreciated. I have no idea how to use the variable scope article posted.

Comment: How do you define `$MySearchField`? post the complete function

Comment: A simple scope issue, see the duplicate. The best solution is probably `array_filter($fullLinks, function ($string) use ($MySearchField) { return strpos(...); })`

Comment: @GeraldSchneider $MySearchField= 'MyText';

Comment: @deceze How would I implement that code?

Comment: Basically exactly as I've shown. `$newArray = array_filter($fullLinks, function ($string) use ($MySearchField) { return strpos($string, $MySearchField) !== false; });`

Comment: @deceze I get: Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array

Comment: Maybe I typo'd the variable or you did. Check that `$fullLinks` is correct.

Comment: @deceze Thanks matey, that works. Dreamweaver is throwing me a syntax error but its working fine in my browser. Thank you.